# Setting base object from derived class method

Tags: c++, inheritance, deep-copy

I have a class which stores a pointer to a data chunk and the size of the data. It implements operations like 'head', 'tail',... but it is irrelevant from the question's point of view. I use this instead of std::vector where I do not want deep copying.
However I need to copy the data sometimes, so I have a member function 'duplicate' to do it.

```
struct ByteArray {
    char* data;
    int size;
    ByteArray(char* data, int size) : data(data), size(size) {}
    ByteArray duplicate() const {
        char *duplicatedData = new char[size];
        memcpy(duplicatedData, data, size);
        return ByteArray(duplicatedData, size);
    }
};
```

Now I have a derived class - extending the previous class, where I need a duplicate method too, which calls the base class' duplicate. I have managed to solve it by casting both objects to the base class, but I suspect that this is not the best solution. Am I missing a more obvious solution? Also is this class the right solution to the original problem (not having deep copy) or there is standard solution what I'm not aware of?

```
struct Foo : ByteArray
{
    int bar;
    ... // more members
    Foo(ByteArray &bytes, int bar) : ByteArray(bytes), bar(bar) {}
    Foo duplicate() const {
        Foo dup = *this;
        static_cast<ByteArray&>(dup) = ByteArray::duplicate();
        return dup;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function

Comment: Sorry, I see. Due to several edits the call of the base method remained in this form. I'm aware of the syntax of calling base method (described in the linked answer), but I'm more concerned with the assignment to the object casted to base class. (I'll edit the question now)

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your `Foo` constructor to take a `ByteArray` by *const* reference instead, `duplicate()` would be pretty straightforward:

```
Foo duplicate() const {
    return Foo(ByteArray::duplicate(), bar);
}
```

As-is, you can still do it the same way, just need an extra line:

```
Foo duplicate() const {
    ByteArray ba = ByteArray::duplicate();
    return Foo(ba, bar);
}
```

Comment: I was a few seconds too late.

Comment: Sorry, my question missed the information that I have several members in the actual derived class. Updated now

Comment: @simon Not sure why that matters, just pass more into your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this then...

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ByteArray {
  char* data;
  int size;
  ByteArray(char* data, int size) : data(data), size(size) {}
  void duplicate(ByteArray &toCopy) const {
    cout<<"Byte array duplicate."<<endl;
    char *data = new char[toCopy.size];
    memcpy(data, toCopy.data, size);
  }
};

struct Foo : ByteArray
{
  int bar;
  Foo(ByteArray &bytes, int bar) : ByteArray(bytes), bar(bar) {}
  void duplicate(Foo &toCopy) const {
    cout<<"Foo duplicate."<<endl;
    ByteArray::duplicate(toCopy);
  }
};

int main(){
  char* str = "some data";
  char* null = "";
  ByteArray barr (str, 9);
  ByteArray barr2 = barr;
  barr2.duplicate(barr);

  Foo farr (barr, 2);
  Foo farr2 = farr;
  farr2.duplicate(farr);

}
```

Comment: Yes, but I have several additional members in the actual code's Foo class unfortunately.

Comment: Also, won't this be a stack overflow not calling the base, but the derived duplicate()?

Comment: I fixed it. It demonstrates the calls now too.

Comment: I suppose, but I would rather have only one function call than an assignment with a function call where the class used.

Comment: So you want to be able to use both `foo2=foo.duplicate();` and `foo3=foo;` first meaning deep copy and second meaning shallow copy?

Comment: I think it starts to be come much more difficult. You can check out... http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297024/call-default-copy-constructor-from-within-overloaded-copy-constructor