# Delegating to a default C++ constructor

Tags: c++

Assume a C++ class `A` with members that can all be copied by the their respective copy constructors. We can rely on the default copy constructor for A to copy its members:

```
class A {
  private:
    A(const A&) = default; // We don't really need this line
    int a;
    B b;
    double c;
}
```

But now let's assume that I want to "extend" (or annotate) the default constructor of A so that in *addition* to copying its members, it does something else, e.g. writes a line to a log file.

I.e. I'd like to write something like:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(const A& a) : A::default(A) {
      print("Constructing A\n");
    }
  private:
    // like before
}
```

Unfortunately that is not correct C++ syntax.

So is there a syntax which allows delegating to a default C++ constructor while explicitly defining the same constructor?

Comment: Related: [Call default copy constructor from within overloaded copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297024/call-default-copy-constructor-from-within-overloaded-copy-constructor).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is to move all members into a base class and write the message in a derived class:

```
class A_helper {
  private:
    int a;
    B b;
    double c;
};
class A : public A_helper {
public:
   A() = default;
   A(const A& a) : A_helper(a) {
       print("Constructing A\n");
   }
   A(A&& a) : A_helper(std::move(a)) {
       print("Constructing A\n");
   }
};
```

Comment: I would do the reverse :) making a class `LoggerA` with its special copy constructor, and then that class might be a regular member (or a parent for EBO).

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate to the default constructor like you would default-initialize a member variable:

```
A(const A&) : A()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is what is wanted. They want the copy to happen like the compiler-generated copy constructor does, but then on top also emit a message.

Answer (score 1):

As often, ["We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection." ( "…except for the problem of too many levels of indirection,")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering):

```
struct VerboseA
{
   VerboseA() = default;
   VerboseA(const VerboseA&) { print("Constructing A\n"); }
   VerboseA(VerboseA&&) { print("Constructing A\n"); }
};
```

And then

```
class A : VerboseA // EBO (Empty Base Optimisation)
{
private:
    A(const A&) = default; // We don't really need this line

    int a;
    B b;
    double c;
};
```

or in C++20

```
class A {
private:
    A(const A&) = default; // We don't really need this line

    [[no_unique_address]]VerboseA verbose; // "EBO" equivalent with attribute
    int a;
    B b;
    double c;
};
```